# Is it possible to build a next.js app with two API servers. 1 native Next.js for user auth / 1 Flask for a python webcrawler

Tags: python, rest, flask, next.js, flask-restful

I'd like to build a Next.js frontend / backend that handles all the requests for things like user auth / database queries etc... but add an additional server for a Flask API which can handle requests between the Next frontend and a Python web crawler.

I understand I need to create a Rest API to communicate between the javascript and python scripts but all the documentation I read has me replacing my entire back end with Flask and I'd rather create an additional API to Next.js' native one rather than replacing it.

What would the architecture for a project like this look like in a way that could be supported in production with Vercel?

Any examples or documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the question. if you're asking if it's just possible, yes it is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RamiDridi, honestly that is all I needed to know. With some research into Flask and some brute force I got it up and running. -Thanks